# .tsx files throw errors while .js files work fine

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, visual-studio-code

in react-native, when I try to pass parameters to functions/components/etc, typescript files will always complain and it won't work until I have specified the type which often is confusing and the code looks way more like spaghetti..

When using .js file with the same code, everything works fine. Also, there are no errors shown in `VSCode` when there are missing imports or wrong types being passed. Is there any *proper* way to handle this? Should I only use `.tsx` for `react-native` ? can I somehow get a sweet-spot between having errors  with `.tsx` files and not having any Intellisense with `.js` files?

Btw: I dont need help fixing the errors in the pictures, I want to avoid that they're being shown as errors.

Thanks in Advance.
[image: passing parameters error]
[image: example error]

Comment: Please post code as formatted text rather than pictures of formatted text.

Comment: Everything you need to know is in there. Using the react-native-navigation examples from snack, they also have `.js` files. When I change the ending to `.tsx` it errors. Definately no code error.

Comment: @codedor, Dave is asking you to post your code as text, in addition to screenshots. If someone wanted to try to reproduce your issue, they can't copy/paste from a screenshot.

Comment: The point of TypeScript is that it can check your types. Using it and then complaining that it is doing what it is designed to seems a bit odd.

Comment: Why are you using typescript if you don't want to use types and type checking? Just use JS if you don't want types.

Comment: Do you know that Typescript is just Javascript with types? It isn't any different. The only thing you gain from it are types and type checking. If you don't want that, plain Javascript works just fine.

Comment: Also, just to share an opinion, you gain a lot from using Typescript and properly typing your app. It's worth learning and implementing in your project, even if it's a challenge to begin with.

Comment: @codedor Please see this [meta FAQ regarding posting images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Answer (score 0):

You need to type those parameters since this file is TypeScript now.

I don't know the shape of `navigation`, `route` and `user`, but to get rid of the errors, you could type those values as `any`:

```js
export function AuthStack({navigation, route}: any) {}
```

and

```js
const [user, setUser] = useState<any>(null);
```

Comment: yeah, thats what I also tried, but it makes the whole code so unreadable if I use anything else than `any`..

Comment: You're going to have to type these values properly. For instance, if `user` is a string, then it would look like `useState<string>(null)`. If user is an object that takes an `id` number and a `name` string, it would look like `useState<{ id: number; name: string;}>(null)`. TypeScript takes some getting used to.

Comment: @codedor "Unreadable" is subjective. It's not "unreadable" if you know TypeScript. Whether or not TS makes sense for *you* is a separate issue.

Answer (score 0):

Files .js are just javaScript, jsx ("React syntax") can run in there or in a .jsx file. But .ts and .tsx are typeScript files, which means that your javaScript now would needs types for the code. You can read more about it on:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/

An easy way to solve the problem is the Ali Klein answer. Or actually use the right types for those variables. For exmaple: `useState<string|null>(null);`

If you don't want to use types, why not use .jsx instead .tsx for the files?

Another option would be use the comment `//@ts-ignore` over each line with type checking